# Relay Module with Arduino Uno and K-Type Thermocouple

Tags: relay, mains, thermocouple, arduino-uno

I am working on a project for school. The goal is to use thermocouples to measure temperatures. The measured temp will control whether or not the lightbulb is turned on. The components used will be an Arduino Uno, K-Type Thermocouple, [AD8495 Analog Amp](https://learn.adafruit.com/ad8495-thermocouple-amplifier/pinouts), and a relay module.

The relay will control 120 Vac to the light bulb. The following schematic was created.

[image]

My question is two-fold.

1. Is this schematic showing the proper routing that would result in basic use and operation?
2. Is using an analog output amp feasible in this situation? I have little experience with coding and have been told that using analog is easier than digital. Would it be easier to use a digital output amp such as the [MAX31855 Amplifier](https://learn.adafruit.com/thermocouple/arduino-code).

Any advice or input is appreciated!

Comment: You need a power supply. For school use a low voltage light would be safer than a 120 V one.

Comment: @GrahamNye Power supply is provided and set at 120V for this application.

Comment: @Sam2022, few questions: (Q1) What is the Temperature range you wish to operate? If it is lower than 100°C/212°F, Thermocouples are not the best sensor choice, being less accurate and requiring an interface module as you mentioned. For up to 150°C / 300°F a thermistor (NTC) is more sensitive. NTC non-linearity can be compensated calculating the “Beta parameter Equation” (Google it) and using beta values (specified or obtained from calibration). Then you may know the actual temperature for the resistance of the NTC.

Comment: (Q2) MAX31855 is really necessary for your application? It is a great IC, with Cold Junction compensation, but its ColdJunction error can be +/- 2C (+/- 4F). The Max AD translates the result into a 14bit word, so Resolution is 1/4 °C. For a wide operating range, of 500°C, Thermocouples are great, but if COST is important, for a school project as an egg incubator, water heater, etc,  for each MAX31855+Thermocouple wiring you may invest US$10. Using an NTC and doing the AD conversion by the Arduino itself, would be cheaper to invest or repair and give you more fun.